# grep exact match at the begining of the file

Tags: grep

I tried the below greps but they don't retrieve any thing. how to retrieve only lines that contain `624` at the beginning of the file and not `1624` for ex, nor `624` in other fields? Fields are separated by `|`

```
grep '^624$' names.dmp | less 
grep -Fx 624 names.dmp | head
```

many thanks

Carol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is space separated:

```
awk '$1=="624"' names.dmp
```

If your grep supports `-w` you can use:

```
grep -w "^624" names.dmp
```

`-w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words`

or

```
grep  "^624 " names.dmp
```

(See the space after `624`)

---

PS If data is separated by `|`, then you need this `awk`

```
awk -F\| '$1=="642"' names.dmp
```

And for `grep` this should do:

```
grep "^642|" names.dmp
```

Comment: The answer with awk works better because grep '^624' yourfile retrieves the lines with starting with 624 like 62456 and not only exact match with 624

Comment: so far, none of the grep script has worked because there is a \t| between the fields.

Do I have to use awk if I want to grep an exact match in a perl program or can grep do the job? the following doesn't work:

Comment: @carol `grep -w` works for me with this line `624     | more`. If it does not work, update your original post with the data you have, so we do not need to guess.

Comment: I used this: is it not correct

grep '^642\t' nodes.dmp

Comment: @carol Then try this: `grep "^624[[:space:]]"`  Why not use the  `-w` or `awk`.  And please post your data.

Comment: It didn't output any thing. Here is an extract of my data

642     9913
1642    9986
2642    5111
3642    4932
4642    4932
5642    7120
5691    7642
6420    6239
6421    6239

Comment: @carol Update your original post and use `code` tags.

Comment: It didn't output any thing. Here is an extract of my data 

`code`
642 9913 1642 9986 2642 5111 3642 4932 4642 4932 5642 7120 5691 7642 6420 6239 6421 6239 

`code`

Comment: @carol Update you post, the post where you ask `I tried the below greps but ...` In this comment I do not see the formatting!!!